# android download multiple imges from server and store in sd card and retrieve using picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

I am searching lots of
please help me to 
how to download multiple images from server and stores in sd card and how to retrieve using picasso library...and as well as zoom that images

Comment: i want all code using picasso can i do that with store in sd card as well as retrieve

Comment: Are you getting the response? Are you parsing the response? If yes. Paste it.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically Set the Image URL to Image view using Picasso without downloading the image.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mDataList.get(position).getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.image_bg).
                        error(R.drawable.image_bg).into(mIvImageView);
```

If you want to zoom the Image you can set the zoom property to the image view. For that, you need to create a custom image view. Please check the below code.

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int mode = NONE;
    Matrix matrix;
    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;
    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                    origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                    origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            // Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                    || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                    - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                    - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to download the Image to SD Card, you can use a background service or async task to download the image dynamically. For that you can use the following code in Service or Async Task:

public String downloadImageFromUrl(String mImagePath, int mtileId) {

```
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String localFileName = "";
    String localTempFileName = "";
    File targetFile=null;
    try {
       File dir =  getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
        if(dir.getFreeSpace()< DownloadsCleanupService.MINIMUM_SPACE)
            DownloadsCleanupService.startImmediateCleanupAction(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String extension = mImagePath.substring(mImagePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        try {
            localTempFileName ="temp"+
                    mtileId + "." + extension;

            localFileName =
                    mtileId + "." + extension;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Checking if file already exists in device or not
          targetFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),localFileName);
        if (targetFile.exists()) {
            targetFile.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return targetFile.getCanonicalPath();
        } else {
            URL url = new URL(mImagePath);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        File targetTempFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),localTempFileName);
            int downloaded = 0;
            if (targetTempFile.exists()) {
                downloaded = (int) targetTempFile.length();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
            } else {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
            }
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            outStream =  openFileOutput(localTempFileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            targetTempFile.renameTo(targetFile);
            targetFile.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        return targetFile.getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            outStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


    }
    return "";
}
```